# Wildcard subdomain directory names

Tags: apache-2.2, wildcard-subdomain

I have the following in my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/%0
  ServerAlias *.test.galapagos.office
</VirtualHost>
```

In /var/www/hosts, I have a directory called jason.test.galapagos.office and one called bill.test.galapagos.office. If I go to jason.test.galapagos.office in a browser, I get what I expect to see. Same with bill. In other words, everything is working perfectly.

However, I'm not quite satisfied with what's going on. Instead of /var/www/hosts/jason.test.galapagos.office and /var/www/hosts/bill.test.galapagos.office/, I'd like /home/jason/web and /home/bill/web.

How can I tell Apache to map to those subdirectories instead?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/%0
  VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%1/web
  ServerAlias *.test.galapagos.office
</VirtualHost>
```

I believe that will sent requests to "jason.test.galapagos.office" to "/home/jason/web"

The full list of VirtualDocumentRoot directives can be found here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

```
0     the whole name
1     the first part
2     the second part
-1    the last part
-2    the penultimate part
2+    the second and all subsequent parts
-2+   the penultimate and all preceding parts
1+ and -1+     the same as 0
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was after. The "%1" was the key part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could this change work?

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%0/web
```

Or you may consider enabling mod_userdir, that by default would look like `http://test.galapagos.office/~bill/`

Comment: That wouldn't quite get me what I want. With that solution, my directories would still have to look like this: /home/jason.test.galapagos.office/web instead of like this: /home/jason/web.